# Calculating network devices energy usage with PromQL query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I've got a power PromQL query working on Grafana below:

```
sum(rPDUIdentDevicePowerWatts{instance=~"192.168.1.101|192.168.1.102|192.168.1.103|192.168.1.104|192.168.1.105|192.168.1.106|192.168.1.107|192.168.1.108", job="snmp",mib="apcups"})/1000
```

This query generates power consumption graph (in kW) from all devices with ip addresses:

```
192.168.1.101|192.168.1.102|192.168.1.103|192.168.1.104|192.168.1.105|192.168.1.106|192.168.1.107|192.168.1.108
```

According above I would like to have another graph to see an energy consumption (kWh) for these same ip addresses.

I produced a query below:

```
sum(rPDUIdentDevicePowerWatts{instance=~"192.168.1.101|192.168.1.102|192.168.1.103|192.168.1.104|192.168.1.105|192.168.1.106|192.168.1.107|192.168.1.108", job="snmp",mib="apcups"})/1000)*0.005555556
```

where value sample time is 20 seconds (1/180=0.005555556)
And it displays energy usage for every 20s.

Now I should add all values together to receive current energy usage (using sum_over_time function):

```
sum_over_time(sum(rPDUIdentDevicePowerWatts{instance=~"192.168.1.101|192.168.1.102|192.168.1.103|192.168.1.104|192.168.1.105|192.168.1.106|192.168.1.107|192.168.1.108", job="snmp",mib="apcups"})/1000)*0.005555556
```

But error occurs:

```
Error executing query: parse error at char 213: expected type range vector in call to function "sum_over_time", got instant vector
```

I also added a time frame below:

```
sum_over_time(sum(rPDUIdentDevicePowerWatts{instance=~"192.168.1.101|192.168.1.102|192.168.1.103|192.168.1.104|192.168.1.105|192.168.1.106|192.168.1.107|192.168.1.108", job="snmp",mib="apcups"})/1000)*0.005555556[24h]
```

Another error occurs:

```
Error executing query: parse error at char 211: range specification must be preceded by a metric selector, but follows a *promql.NumberLiteral instead
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to prometheus document [Query Function | Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) , function **sum_over_time(range-vector)** need to calculate through range vector. please try

```html
sum_over_time(
    rPDUIdentDevicePowerWatts{instance=~"192.168.1.101|192.168.1.102|192.168.1.103|192.168.1.104|192.168.1.105|192.168.1.106|192.168.1.107|192.168.1.108", job="snmp",mib="apcups"}[24h]
)/1000)*0.005555556
```

Answer (score 0):

If time series values are sampled every 20 seconds, then the following query should return summary energy consumption in [Joules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule) for the last 24 hours (see `[24h]` in the query):

```
sum(sum_over_time(
rPDUIdentDevicePowerWatts{instance=~"192.168.1.101|192.168.1.102|192.168.1.103|192.168.1.104|192.168.1.105|192.168.1.106|192.168.1.107|192.168.1.108", job="snmp",mib="apcups"}[24h]))*20
```

The energy consumption in Joules can be converted to kWh by dividing the result by `3600000`:

```
sum(sum_over_time(
rPDUIdentDevicePowerWatts{instance=~"192.168.1.101|192.168.1.102|192.168.1.103|192.168.1.104|192.168.1.105|192.168.1.106|192.168.1.107|192.168.1.108", job="snmp",mib="apcups"}[24h]))*20/3600000
```

Update: the `sum_over_time(m[d])*20` can be substituted with `integrate(m[d])` when using VictoriaMetrics. The [integrate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#integrate) function works with arbitrary interval between samples.